# Create list of lists from list based on criteria

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings that I am trying to convert into a list of lists based on when a  specific character appears in the list. Below is an example:

I am starting with the following list:

```
lst = ['ab', 'c1', 'cd', 'd2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'ax', 'by', 'cz', 'dzz']
```

I want to convert `lst` into a list of lists where each list begins where there is a string that starts with "a" and ends one element before the next string that starts with "a". The result should look like this:

```
new_lst = [['ab', 'c1', 'cd', 'd2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['ax', 'by', 'cz', 'dzz']]
```

What I have tried was to find the index of all elements that begin with "a", and I do so with the following code `indices = [idx for idx, x in enumerate(lst) if x.startswith('a')]`. This got me the position of each string that matched that criteria. This yielded `[0, 4, 7]`

Then I looked into splitting the list using the ranges created from the indices. So split at ranges (0,3), (4,6), and (7,10). I've been at it for hours and I can't figure out how to do this dynamically. Couldn't find any solutions online either. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. Or perhaps my approach wasn't the most ideal from the start.

Comment: Your approach looks fine to me. What's the issue with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

lst = ["ab", "c1", "cd", "d2", "a1", "b1", "c1", "ax", "by", "cz", "dzz"]
indices = [idx for idx, x in enumerate(lst) if x.startswith("a")]
print([each_split.tolist() for each_split in np.split(lst, indices) if len(each_split)])
```

Comment: Yup, this works. I was wondering if you can break down that last line? I can't wrap my head around how you got np.split to split the list at each position indicated in indices.

Comment: You can firstly check out the numpy docs for split: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html. Coming to the explanation of the line, after getting the output of the split, each element is still in a numpy array format. We convert it back to a list using the `.tolist` method. We also have  a check for the length of the split to skip empty arrays. You can mark the answer as an accepted solution if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy does the job but your approach was also good ! Moreover, it could be interesting to see your code and work on it, rather than giving you the solution !

Like you said, you just have to iterate through your **indices** list and create ranges. To do this, consider to add the end of the list ! :

```
max_idx = len(lst)
append(max_idx)
print(idx)
>> [0, 4, 7, 11]
```

Then, you just have to construct your ranges :

```
new_lst = []
# the idea is to only iterate on [0, 4, 7] 
# to create then the ranges [(0,4), (4,7), (7,11)]
# in python list[0:4] will take indexes 0,1,2,3 but not 4 
for i in range(len(idx)-1):
    new_lst.append(lst[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])
print(new_lst)
>> [['ab', 'c1', 'cd', 'd2'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['ax', 'by', 'cz', 'dzz']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try numpy.split

```
idx = [lst.index(a) for a in lst if a.lower()[0] == 'a']
new_lst = np.split(lst, idx)

[array([], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['ab', 'c1', 'cd', 'd2'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], dtype='<U3'),
 array(['ax', 'by', 'cz', 'dzz'], dtype='<U3')]
```

Comment: this might not work if `lst` has duplicates, as `lst.index` will pick up the index of the first one.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem yes, that is true. Thank you for noting that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def listoflists(l):  
    new_lst=[]
    a=[] 
    c=0
    
    for i in l:
        if i[0]=='a':
            c+=1
            if c<2:
                a.append(i)
                
            else:
                new_lst.append(a)
                a=[]
                a.append(i)
        else:
            a.append(i)    
    new_lst.append(a)
    return(new_lst)  
    
l = ['ab', 'c1', 'cd', 'd2', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'ax', 'by', 'cz', 'dzz','an','bw','ey']            
print(listoflists(l))
```

Comment: This is a simple solution you can try this